# jquery appendTo() with divs, strange behavior

Tags: jquery, appendto

I am using Jquery, making table cells that contain multiple divs.  the divs contain some data and a radio button.  my code works, but i want to know why i had to use a "middle-man" variable.  seems really weird to me, was very frustrating, and im curious why. perhaps i just dont undestand this well enough.  here is my code

```
    // my radio button
    var rad_button = $('<input type="radio"...'
    // my object, div w some attributes, text
    var my_Object = $('<div class="selected...'
    rad_button.prependTo(my_Object);

    var middle_man = my_Object;
    middle_man.appendTo(bigger_object);
```

this is the only way i could get this to work.  i tried the more direct way:

```
    my_object.appendTo(bigger_object);
```

but that didnt work.  anyone able to tell me why this is done this way?

Comment: That's a `TYPO` my_Object != my_object

Comment: @Olaf, there is an empty line between your call to `prependTo()` and your having to alias `middle_man` to `my_Object` for your code to work. Is this meaningful, and does part of the code under the line break reside in some kind of asynchronous callback, or is it just a matter of casing between `my_Object` and `my_object`?

Comment: make a not working fiddle with that and it's probably like Musa said.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just chain your append calls together on the table cell you are creating?

```
$('<td />')
  .append($('<input />', { 'type':'radio' }))
  .append($('<div />', { 'class':'selected' }));
```

Should output HTML

```
<td>
  <input type="radio" />
  <div class="selected"></div>
</td>
```

No middle man.